# Происхождение слова "промысел"

Tags: этимология

Однокоренное со словом "мысль"?

Answer (score 2):

Я подозреваю, что современное нам слово "промысел" является общей итоговой формой эволюции двух изначально разных слов. Одно из них ("промысел" - в смысле "Божий промысел") должно быть родственно слову "мысль" и является синонимом слова "замысел".  Другое ("промысел" как добыча) может быть родственно слову "мысь" (белка). Дело в том, что в древности беличьи шкурки нередко играли роль денег. Скажем, мыт (налог) мог исчисляться в мысях (беличьих шкурах) с каждой избы.

Answer (score 0):

Этимологически несомненно, в современном русском - понятия не имею.